# Vbs regex how to deal with multiple matches

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a pattern with which I find one match. How should I deal with the other matches in case I have multiple choices

```
    Dim re, targetString, colMatch, objMatch
Set re = New regexp
With re
  .pattern = ">([\s,\S]*?)<" 
  .Global = True
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .Multiline = True
End With
targetString = ">test and test<  >test2 and test2<   >test3 and test3<"
Set colMatch = re.Execute(targetString)
For Each objMatch In colMatch
result = objMatch.SubMatches.Item(0)
Next
```

At the present I am getting only "test3 and test3", but how can I get the others?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example below. It shows how to put all submatches into array.

```
Dim strSourceString, objMatch, arrResults
strSourceString = ">test and test<  >test2 and test2<   >test3 and test3<"
Set objList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With New RegExp
    .Pattern = ">([\s,\S]*?)<"
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    For Each objMatch In .Execute(strSourceString)
        objList(objList.Count) = objMatch.SubMatches.Item(0)
    Next
End With
arrResults = objList.Items
Set objList = Nothing
MsgBox Join(arrResults, "; ") ' array contains submatches
```

Comment: omegastripes, great thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to process `result` before you end the loop with `next`.

Currently, you assign each of the results to `result`, but then immediately end the loop and move on to the next result.

Comment: maybeWeCouldStealAVan,  Thank you for your comment. Could you please provide a working example

Comment: @Alex Could you please try it yourself?